# Word metric on a finitely generated subgroup versus the word metric of its finitely generated parent

Tags: group-theory, metric-spaces, geometric-group-theory, finitely-generated, combinatorial-group-theory

Let $G$ be a finitely generated group and $H\subseteq G$ a finitely generated subgroup. For every finite set of a generators $F$ for $H$, we can extend to a finite generating set $\hat{F}$ for $G$. Denoting the word metrics on $H$ and $G$ with respect to these generating sets by $d_{1}(x,y)$ and $d_{2}(x,y)$, what relationships exist between $d_{1}$ and $d_{2}$. Presumably for all $x,y\in H$ we have that $d_{1}(x,y)\geq d_{2}(x,y)$, but can we say something more specific?

Edit: The word metric on a group $G$ with respect to a finite generating set $F=\{a_{1},\ldots,a_{n}\}$ is defined in the following way. For an element $x\in G$ the natural number $|x|$ is the length of the shortest word in $F$ and inverses of elements thereof that is equal to $x$. The word metric on $G$ with respect to $F$ is defined by setting $d(x,y):=|xy^{-1}|$.

Comment: Could you please define the the word metric on a group?

Comment: Yes, apologies for the omission.

Comment: You would probably be interested in the concept of (un)distorted subgroups which is (coarsely) about comparing the intrinsic geometry of a subgroup(with its own word metric) to how it sits in the full group. Not really sure what you are looking for as "more specific"

Comment: If $H$ has finite index in $G$ then the two groups are quasi-isometric, which is a strong relationship between $d_1$ and $d_2$, but I don't know what can be said in general

Comment: If the embedding is a "quasi-isometry" then you can say stuff. You cannot say much in general.

Comment: The relevant keyword is "distortion". Namely the distortion function maps $n$ to $\sup\{d_1(x,1):\; x\in H,\;d_2(x,1)\le n\}$. Its asymptotic behavior doesn't depend on the choice of generating subset. Distortion in $O(n)$ is called undistorted subgroup, and means $H$ is QI-embedded into $G$. Distortion is an intense subject of study. For instance in a polycyclic group, the only possible distortion of an infinite cyclic subgroup is polynomial of integer degree or exponential. In a higher rank arithmetic lattice it is linear or exponential. In many groups it can only be linear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you have $d_1(x,y) \geq \ d_2(x,y)$ in the above set up but in general there is not a ton to say. As mentioned in the comments this is this idea of distortion which measures certain aspects of how the subgroup $H$ fits inside the group $G$. If you would like you can look at [this blog post](https://berstein.wordpress.com/2011/05/04/distortion-of-finitely-presented-subgroups-of-non-positively-curved-groups-i/) which discusses some of the ideas and defines this distortion functions, which intuitively compares the intrinsic geometry of the subgroup(its own word metric) and how that subgroup fits inside the full group.

A simple example comes from a Baumslag-Solitar group $G=BS(1,2)= \langle a,t \mid tat^{-1} = a^2 \rangle$(discussed in the above blog post, which you should look at -- it has pictures). Consider $H=\langle a \rangle$ in $G$. Well

$$t^nat^{-n}=t^{n-1} t a t^{-1}t^{-n+1}=t^{n-1} a^2 t^{-n+1}= (t^{n-1} a t^{-n+1}) (t^{n-1}a t^{-n+1})= \dots =a^{2^n} $$

which gives that $d_1(1,a^{2^n})=2^n \geq 2n+1 \geq d_2(1,a^{2^n})$ which is a pretty big difference in the geometry.

Now sometimes you can say more, although normally "coarse-ify" things up to some sort of equivalence so that the choice of generating sets does not change the answer. For example in [hyperbolic groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_group) and CAT(0) groups it is known that abelian subgroups are undistorted/[quasi-isometrically embedded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-isometry).

Comment: This is the kind of thing I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: Are there examples of subgroups that are unbounded in their own metric, but bounded in their parent group? I.e. infinite distortion?

Comment: @RobertThingum Not in finitely generated groups, you can only have finitely many elements in a ball. For infinitely generated yes. In fact there are groups where every word metric gives a bounded metric space but have many subgroups which are unbounded in their own metric.

Comment: I actually [wrote an answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1368933/do-uncountable-groups-have-generating-sets-where-you-can-find-elements-of-arbitr/1369453#1369453) a while ago on this. But one example is any (full)symmetric group on infinitely many elements(which will contain every countable group as a subgroup for example).

Comment: Fascinating. I will look into your answer.

Comment: @RobertThingum It is weird when you first discover(eh it is still pretty weird, although makes a bit more sense to me/ more used to it) that their are infinite groups where it makes sense to say they are "quasi-isometric to a point", which for geometric group theorists that normally means finite groups as we normally think finitely generated groups.

Answer (score 5):

The word metric generalises to something called a "length function". I'll define this properly below, but really a length function $L$ is a function $G\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ satisfying the obvious kind of think, like $L(g)=L(g^{-1})$.

A summary of what follows is:

> The induced word metric on a subgroup $H$ of a finitely presented group $G$ can be, basically, any computable length function.

The motivation here is a question of Gromov, which asks how bad can the distortion of the infinite cyclic group be when embedded in a group? What follows says that "if you can find a length function then there exists a group with the corresponding distortion".

**Definition.**
A *length function* on a group $H$ is a map $L: H\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ such that

1. $L(h)=0$ if and only if $h=1$;
2. $L(h)=L(h^{-1})$ for all $h\in H$;
3. $L(h_1h_2)\leq L(h_1)+L(h_2)$ for all $h_1, h_2\in H$;
4. there exists some $\lambda>0$ such that for all $r\in\mathbb{N}$, the set $\{h\in H\mid L(h)\leq r\}$ contains at most $\lambda^r$ elements.

For example, the word metric defines a length function on any finitely generated group. Moreover, if $H$ is a subgroup of a finitely generated group $G$ then the word metric of $G$ restricted to $H$ is a length function on $H$

**Definition.**
Let $H$ be a finitely generated group. Two length functions $L_1$ and $L_2$ on $H$ are *strongly equivalent* if there exists some $C>0$ such that for all $h\in H$,
$$\frac1CL_1(h)\leq L_2(h)\leq CL_1(h).$$
"Strongly equivalent" is really the same as "equivalent", as changes in generators will alter the length function, but only up to strong equivalence.

We then have the following theorem, which is Theorem 2 of Ol'shanskii, *On the distortion of subgroups of finitely presented groups*, Matematicheskii Sbornik, **188** (1997) pp. 51-98.

> **Theorem.**
>   Let $H$ be a finitely generated group and $L:H\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ a computable length function on $H$. Then $H$ embeds in a finitely presented group $G$ such that $L$ is strongly equivalent to the word metric of $G$ restricted to $H$.

To repeat what I said above, this theorem roughly says that the induced word metric on a subgroup $H$ of a finitely presented group $G$ can be, basically, any "nice-enough" length function.

Of course, "nice-enough" is not necessarily that nice. For example, the Ackermann function is recursive*, and hence computable. There are free groups which embed into "nice" groups with Ackermannian distortion! See the paper      W. Dison, T. Riley, *Hydra groups*, Comm. Math. Helv., **88** (2013) pp. 507–540 ([arxiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1002.1945)).

*but not primitive recursive, which is why it was introduced.

Comment: Another good answer, thank you. It seems that distortion is indeed the name of the game.